# Python почему внутри неизменяемых типов можно менять значения изменяемых типов?

Tags: python, словари, tuple

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
t = (1, 2, d)

t[2]['b'] = 555

t  #вызов кортежа, в итоге изменения будут видны
```

Я немного запутался, кортеж это неизменяемый тип, а словарь изменяемый. Но каким образом в неизменяемом типе отображаются изменения, и почему вообще кортеж поддерживает изменяемые типы если его фишка это неизменяемость.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Понимание того, что кортеж содержит не сам словарь, а всего лишь ссылку на него, может помочь. Т.е. при записи в словарь сам словарь может быть изменен, а вот заменить на другой словарь в кортеже у вас не получится. Вы обращаетесь к одному из членов словаря по ключу `b` по ссылке здесь

```py
t[2]['b'] = 555
```

Неизменяемым будет только содержание самого кортежа, который состоит из ссылок на объекты

эксперимент:

есть кортеж `t`:

```py
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
t = (1, 2, d)
```

спросим какой у него идентификатор и идентификатор одного из членов:

```py
print(id(t))
#out 1721653392256
print(id(t[2]))
#out 1721654101568
```

а также идентификатор для одного из членов словаря по ключу `b`

```py
print(id(t[2]['b']))
#out 1721654045232
```

изменим это значение и посмотрим на изменения идентификаторов:

```py
t[2]['b'] = 555
print(id(t[2]['b']))
#out 1721654045264
```

то есть теперь есть новый объект с новым идентификатором. Или другими словами существует новый объект в памяти на который ведет ссылка, которая хранится в словаре под ключом `b`. Предыдущая ссылка на объект под ключом `b`, то есть  целочиселенная двойка, заменена ссылкой на целочисленое 555. А сам объект в памяти с целочисленной двойкой уничтожен, поскольку нет ни одной действующей ссылки на него.

Вопрос: изменились ли объекты кортежа и члена [2] кортежа?

```py
print(id(t))
#out 1721653392256
print(id(t[2]))
#out 1721654101568
```

Конечно, же, нет!!

И еще одно важное замечание:

*У кортежа нет способа предотвратить изменение значений его элементов, которые являются независимыми объектами и могут быть доступны через ссылки вне кортежа. Словари и другие изменяемые объекты внутри кортежей могут изменяться, но их идентификаторы всегда будут одинаковыми.*

Comment: Цитата: Вопрос: изменились ли объекты кортежа и члена [2] кортежа? - немного запутал ваш ответ на ваш же вопрос.  Объекты кортежа не изменялись, но объекты члена [2] ведь изменились? а именно переписан идентификатор ключа 'b' в словаре, тоесть было изменение? или я вас неправильно понял?  Насколько я понял словарь это коллекция объектов разных типов, в данном случае в словаре хранится тип int который не изменяется и в случае модификации словаря перезаписывается. Можно ли сказать что  ключ: значение равносильно переменная=тип объекта?

Comment: @Alegro попробую другими словами. Кортеж хранит ссылку на объект (а не сам объект). Ссылку (и ее индентификатор) изменить нельзя. Но если под этой ссылкой хранится объект, который можно изменить (словарь), то вы можете его изменить. Ссылка же останется неизменной. А вот в самом словаре появится новая ссылка на объект `int` и поскольку словарь менять можно, то и переписать ссылку под ключом `b` тоже можно.

Comment: @Alegro перезапись в словарь будет означать, что под ключом `b` будет новая ссылка на новый (или старый) объект. В принципах python работа со ссылками уничижает такое понятие как сборщик мусора и если на объект в памяти не ведет ни одна ссылка, то он уничтожается. Очень важно понять, что мы не храним и не работаем с объектами. Мы работаем со ссылками на них