Изменение значения словаря при изменении переменной
Только начинаю изучать python, столкнулся с неочевидным для меня феноменом.
При заполнении значения словаря переменной-словарём оказывается, что после изменения этой переменной меняется и значение в словаре.
var_dict_value = {'one' : 1, 'two' : 2}

var_dict = {}
var_dict ['first'] = var_dict_value

print(var_dict) 
# {'first': {'one': 1, 'two': 2}}


print('chg var_dict_value to 7777')
var_dict_value['one'] = 7777

print(var_dict)
# {'first': {'one': 7777, 'two': 2}}

Из этого я могу сделать вывод, что ссылаясь на переменную мы работаем не с её значением, а с ней как с указателем на значение (я где-то слышал умные слова про то, что в python всё есть объект, но мне это пока ни о чём не говорит).
Но аналогичная ситуация с обычными переменными (не словарями) даёт иной эффект - значение переменной не меняется после изменения переменной, участвующей в её определении
a = 5
b = a

print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}')
# a = 5, b = 5

a = 10
print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}')
# a = 10, b = 5

Отсюда вопросы:

В чём принципиальная разница двух ситуаций? почему в первом кейсе значение (в словаре) меняется после изменения переменной, а во втором - нет
Как "законстантить" значение в случае с словарём? то есть, как добиться того, чтобы при изменении var_dict_value не менялись бы данные в var_dict ?


писал ответ на похожий вопрос здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1369591/209304. Может найдете ответ) с сущностями можно понимать только значения изменяемые и неизменяемые. На второй вопрос можете найти ответ в самом конце по моей ссылке, вместо "кортеж" вставьте нужное вам)

@Dmitry , я вроде понял про ссылку. Но не очень ясна разница с перменными-НЕсловарями
a = 5
b = a
print(f'id(a) = {id(a)}, id(b) = {id(b)}')
id(a) = 140705320203176, id(b) = 140705320203176
a = 10
print(f'id(a) = {id(a)}, id(b) = {id(b)}')
#id(a) = 140705320203336, id(b) = 140705320203176
Изначально id(a) = id(b). Почему после изменения a id различаются?
То есть, понятно, что b != ссылка на a ; b = физически то же значение, что изначально было в a
Но в чём разница "ссылочности" на концептуальном уровне тут и со словарями?
upd: блин, как починить переносы строк в комменте?

@Dmitry
Правильно ли понимаю, что var_dict ['first'] - это ссылка именно на var_dict_value, а не на объект, лежащий по этой (var_dict_value) ссылке? как следствие, тут имеет место именно цепочка var_dict ['first']  -> var_dict_value -> объект. Тогда как в ситуации с переменными a и b обе переменные смотрели сразу на объект, и поэтому не зависили от друг друга?

Уф. В голове ещё остался некий пласт неопределённости, но его я позже себе разжую экспериментами с проверкой id объектов. В любом случае, стало значительно понятнее. Спасибо большое!

Разница в присваивании.

попробую объснить вот на этом примере
a = 5
b = a

print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}')
# a = 5, b = 5

a = 10
print(f'a = {a}, b = {b}')
# a = 10, b = 5

в первых двух строках вы определяете две переменные, которые ссылаются на один объект.
Далее, вы изменяете переменную a, что буквально значит, что вы создаете новый объект в памяти и в переменную a кладете ссылку на него. Следовательно, ссылка на интовое значение 5 после строки a = 10, хранится только в переменной b. И это вы видите когда выводите значение в последней строке.
В этом примере
var_dict_value = {'one' : 1, 'two' : 2}

var_dict = {}
var_dict ['first'] = var_dict_value

print(var_dict) 
# {'first': {'one': 1, 'two': 2}}


print('chg var_dict_value to 7777')
var_dict_value['one'] = 7777

print(var_dict)
# {'first': {'one': 7777, 'two': 2}}

Сущности var_dict ['first'] и var_dict_value ссылаются на один и тот же объект в памяти. Если вы поменяете любой из них, то изменения вы увидите и в другом
Пример номер раз
var_dict ['first']["two"] = 233
print(var_dict_value)
#out
# {'one': 1, 'two': 233}

Пример номер два
var_dict_value["one"] = "blabla"
print(var_dict ['first'])
#out
# {'one': 'blabla', 'two': 233}

Различия здесь таковы, что словарь - это изменяемый тип данных, а вот int - не изменяемый тип данных.
Если зайти поглубже, то можно понять, что переменные под ключами словаря тоже не изменяемые и при переопределении так же создается новый объект в памяти и ссылка на него, которая будет лежать под ключом словаря =) а старые объекты будут уничтожены (интовые значения 1 и 2) после последнего изменения, поскольку нет ни одной ссылки, которые будут вести на эти объекты
Чтобы избежать изменений описанных выше необходимо использовать методы copy() и deepcopy(). Различия можно прочесть в документации.
Коротко
copy() - создает новый объект, а затем (насколько это возможно, стоит проверять "насколько") вставляет в него ссылки на объекты, найденные в оригинале.
deepcopy() - создает новый объект, а затем рекурсивно вставляет в него копии объектов, найденных в оригинале.
PS: изменяемые объекты, которые доступны по ссылке могут быть изменены и не существует механизма предотвратить это. Это ответственность программиста использовать верные типы данных и следить за правильной их обработкой
